# Get Document from Firestore by ID

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a document from Firestore by the ID but it doesnt work. An empty document is returned.

I want to get the document with ID '5a' from collection 'class'.

Here is a picture of Firestore web:

[image]

And that is the way, I am trying to get the data:

```
DocumentSnapshot doc = await db.collection('class').doc('5a').get();

print(doc.exists()); // => false
```

But no filled document is returned.

(Permissions are not required and I am getting no error.)

Here is the whole code for the methode

```
Future<Class> getClassFromFirestore(String clas) async {

DocumentSnapshot doc = await db.collection('class').doc('5a').get();

    SplayTreeMap<String, List<Lesson>> days = SplayTreeMap();
    List<String> subjects = [];
    try {
      (await doc[ClassFields.days]).forEach((date, lessonsRaw) async {
        print('hep');
        List<Lesson> lessons = [];
        lessonsRaw.forEach((lessonRaw) async {
          Lesson lesson = Lesson(
            id: lessonRaw[LessonFields.id].toString().trim(),
            timeblock: int.parse(lessonRaw[LessonFields.timeblock].toString().trim()), 
            subject: lessonRaw[LessonFields.subject].toString().trim(), 
            teacher: lessonRaw[LessonFields.teacher].toString().trim(), 
            room: lessonRaw[LessonFields.room].toString().trim()
          );
          lessons.add(lesson);
        });
        days[date] = lessons;
      });
      (await doc[ClassFields.subjects]).forEach((subject) {
        subjects.add(subject.toString());
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      // cant get doc
    }

    print(days);

    return Class(name: clas, days: days, subjects: subjects);
  }
```

Comment: can you print the doc's data like this and see what it prints, print(doc.data());

Comment: Try reinstalling the app, it's weird

Comment: @Gwhyyy doc.data(); -> null is returned. That really seems like there is something wrong :(

Comment: can you include the whole method code you tried

Comment: @Gwhyyy I added the method. Its just the beginning of the method. In the following code, I convert the json object map the includes my object class.